# Vue Single File Component stuck webpack dev server

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to load the following single file component:

I'm creating a instant messaging app

## It's a big html file

https://pastebin.com/cxPmFGQe

```
<div id="chats-component" class="web">
  <div id="app">
    <div class="_1FKgS app-wrapper-web bFqKf">
      <span>
        <div tabindex="-1" id="modal-contacts" style="display:none">
          <span class="_3rsak">
            <div data-animate-modal-backdrop="true" class="_3gUiM copyable-area" style="opacity: 1;">
              <div class="_2dA13">
                <div class="_1CnF3 _12a60" data-animate-modal-popup="true"
                  style="opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);">
```

But the dev server console got stuck and keeps showing 40%

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've already tried:

1. to create other Vue app
2. not load the big style.css file (because it´s so big could also cause problems)
3. when I comment the component on vue-router the dev server compiler runs normally.

What could be happening?

## Edited

When I comment the component loading in router/index.js then loading the dev server is 'normal'

[image]

Comment: this happens to me usually ... believe it or not ..when i keep pressing `enter` key it continues

Comment: @Dadboz... I wish it was that easy... i got to tell... I´ve tried pressing enter and many other keys... but I guess you´re more luck than I am right now....:)... the node js instance on the task manager just goes wild... and takes all the cpu time

Comment: this is "awkward" ... usually if something is wrong the prompt throws an error ...considering the fact that your CPU is getting a bottleneck ... i wonder how BIG is this HTML file xD

Comment: doesn't look too big to cause such issues

Comment: @Dadboz... yes.. no console error messages... only symptom that something is not going well is the fact of not going beyond this point...if you say that is not big enough to cause problems then I believe you because I´ve already made a sfc relatively as big as this and had no trouble with it... so that make me wonder what´s happening... could it be something related with the css file perhaps? It has around 16000 lines of css.... I´ll make a `style.css` on pastbin to show the css file... I guess it´s not the style.css file because it´s commented... it´s not loading...